# in r: select pairs of cases with predefined difference

Tags: r

I am a new user of R trying to select pairs of cases from two groups so that their difference in a reference variable is less than a criterion value (e.g 50). However, I would like to form only pairs that are composed of unique cases (so I need to remove each subject that is already forming part of a selected pair) and get as many pairs as possible.

My data includes >200 variables but those relevant to this problem are: one variable indicating the subject's ID, another for the group (coded as 1 or 0), the variable X for which the difference of each pair is <50. The other variables ("keeping variables") are the ones I want to explore in the sample composed by pairs.

A simple example (with just two "keeping variables") would look like:

```
    structure(list(subject = 1:10, group = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1), reference = c(1347.751, 1458.496, 1449.232, 1267.118, 
    1410.963, 1314.72, 1264.212, 1288.022, 1269.86, 1455.971), var1 = 
    c(3.715, 3.964, 4.027, 4.292, 4.341, 4.314, 3.37, 3.209, 3.441, 
    4.356), var2 = c(10.136, 9.295, 11.653, 9.863, 10.915, 9.92, 
    9.595, 11.898, 9.669, 12.405)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = 
    "data.frame")
```

Thanks in advance for any possible help

Comment: What would your desired output look like? It seems that there would be several admissible outputs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Otto. The desired final output would be a data frame solely containing the cases that belong to pairs created according to the defined criteria (that is that each pair member comes from a different group, that their difference in the variable "reference" is <50 and that the same subject is not included in more than one pair). My aim is to perform group comparisons in the "keeping variables" but just using this subset of individuals with similar values in the reference variable

Comment: Should subject 4 in group 0 be matched with subject 8 or 9 in group 1?

Comment: Subject 4 could be indistinctly paired with subject 8 or 9 (as both pairs satisfy the imposed conditions) although, in principle, the pair with the smallest difference would be preferable as it would allow obtaining groups with more similar averages. However, because the same subject cannot be included in two pairs, in larger datasets choosing one or another case might be affected by previously formed pairs or affect the formation of subsequent pairs.